# RobotFramework - Handle 2 Browser tabs at the same time and test them

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, testing, robotframework

I have this problem where i need to test a functionality of my web app with 2 tabs open and check if I update someting on tab 1 Tab 2 refreshes, I am trying to get this done using the `Press key` keyword.

I am targeting the body of and Using the Ascii number for `CTRL+T` to open a new tab, A new browser window opens rather than a New Tab i am using latests version of Chrome.

I have also tried to to use `\\09`  but that gives me the same result

```
Press Key  tag=body   \\20
```

Then i try to go back to the window using the  `Select Window  MAIN` Keyword but that doesn't work.

**QUESTION: how can i open 2 tabs at the same time and test them using `RobotFramework` with `SeleniumLibrary`?**

Comment: Is it _really_ important that you have two tabs, versus two browser windows? I think for all browsers, a new tab is no different than a new window from a memory and process perspective. The only real difference is just cosmetic. Wouldn't your test be just as valid for two windows as it would be for two tabs in one window?

Comment: @BryanOakley It is not that important. I tried to use 2 diffrent windows but i was not able to switch between them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your test would be just as valid with two windows as it would with one window and two tabs.

You can call the [open browser](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Open%20Browser) keyword multiple times, giving each window its own unique alias. You can then switch between them with the [switch browser](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Switch%20Browser) keyword and the appropriate alias.

### Example

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

Suite Teardown  close all browsers

*** Variables ***
${browser}  chrome

*** Test cases ***
Example using two windows
    open browser  http://www.example.com  ${browser}  alias=tab1
    open browser  http://www.w3c.org      ${browser}  alias=tab2

    switch browser  tab1
    location should be  http://www.example.com/

    switch browser  tab2
    location should be  https://www.w3.org/
```

Comment: Great! Direct to the point and simple enough to be understood by beginners
Thank you!